# Не могу вывести данные из базы данных в JTable

Tags: java, swing, jdbc

Подскажите, имеется такой код, как мне из базы данных вывести ВСЕ данные в JTable?
Чтобы я ни делал, в JTable выводится только одна строчка данных и названия столбцов.

```
import com.mysql.cj.protocol.Resultset;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Wydatki implements StartInterface{
    private Object[][] data;
    private Object[] columnsHeader;
    DefaultTableModel tableModel;
    JTable jtable;
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();

    JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
    JPanel jpanel = new JPanel();
    public Wydatki(String NickName,String Rok,String Miesiac){
        StartInterface.StartJMenu(jframe,NickName);
        jframe.add(jpanel);
        jframe.setTitle("Wydatki");

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException) {
            classNotFoundException.printStackTrace();
        }
        String username = "root";
        String password = "QWERTY123";
        String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/centus_database";

        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, username, password);

            String sql = "select dzien,Zywnosc,Mieszkianie,Media,Transport,Ubrania,Rachunki,Rozrywka,Suma_wydatkow from wydatki where NickName = ? and rok = ? and miesiac = ?";
            PreparedStatement prestmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            prestmt.setString(1,NickName);
            prestmt.setString(2,Rok);
            prestmt.setString(3,Miesiac);

            ResultSet resultSet = prestmt.executeQuery();

            while(resultSet.next())
            {
                Object[][] data = new Object [][]{
                        {resultSet.getString("dzien"),resultSet.getString("Zywnosc"),resultSet.getString("Mieszkianie"),
                                resultSet.getString("Media"),resultSet.getString("Transport"),
                                resultSet.getString("Ubrania"),resultSet.getString("Rachunki"),resultSet.getString("Rozrywka"),resultSet.getString("Suma_wydatkow")}
                        };

                columnsHeader = new String[] {"Dzien","Zywnosc","Mieszkanie","Media","Transport","Ubrania","Rachunki","Rozrywka","Suma"};


                jtable = new JTable(data, columnsHeader);
                scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jtable);
                jtable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
                jpanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                jpanel.add(jtable.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
                jpanel.add(jtable, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                jpanel.setVisible(true);

            }

        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: вы в цикле с каждой итерацией пересоздаете таблицу вот в этой строке jtable = new JTable(data, columnsHeader);

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду создать цикл for и с каждым последующим увеличение итерации просто-напросто пересоздавать jtable?
Я что-то не до конца понимаю, если вам не сложно, покажите, как это должно выглядеть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ResultSet чем-то напоминает итератор. У вас есть какое-то количество данных, однако, представьте, что они записаны построчно. Кроме того, есть курсор, который указывает на текущую строку (строку , на которой вы остановились, выполняя чтение). У вас в руках есть только 1 механизм для чтения этих данных - вызов next , который передвинет курсор на следующую строку, если она имеется. Та строка, на которой находится курсор, и приходит к вам на обработку. Но курсор единовременно указывает только на одну строку, а вам нужно прочитать все строки. Поэтому вы используете цикл. В теле цикла вы получите все строки поочередно. Все хорошо, но таблица , в которую вы пишите, пересоздается в теле цикла. Т.е. вы всегда при 1 итерации добавляете в новосозданную таблицу 1 строку. Следующий цикл - новая таблица с добавлением одной строки. Поскольку перменная для таблицы одна, то таблица, созданная на предыдущей итерации больше не имеет ссылок и ее удаляет сборщик мусора.

К сожалению, это далеко не единственная проблема этого кода. Я немного подправил класс, но привести его в нормальный вид невозможно, для этого нужно рефакторит код всего приложения.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Wydatki extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6846421395193283567L;

    private final static String username = "root";
    private final static String password = "QWERTY123";
    private final static String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/centus_database";
    private final static String sql = "select dzien,Zywnosc,Mieszkianie,Media,Transport,Ubrania,Rachunki,"
            + "Rozrywka,Suma_wydatkow from wydatki where NickName = ? and rok = ? and miesiac = ?";
    private final static Object[] columnsHeader = new String[]{"Dzien", "Zywnosc", "Mieszkanie", "Media", 
        "Transport", "Ubrania", "Rachunki", "Rozrywka", "Suma"};
    private final static Connection connection;
    static {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, username, password);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    public Wydatki(String nickName, String rok, String miesiac) {
        try {
            init(nickName, rok, miesiac);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
    
    private void init(String nickName, String rok, String miesiac) throws SQLException {
        
        //это МАКСИМАЛЬНО странная строка кода
        StartInterface.StartJMenu(this, nickName);
        
        JTable jtable = new JTable(findData(nickName, rok, miesiac), columnsHeader);
        jtable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        JPanel jpanel = new JPanel();
        jpanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        jpanel.add(jtable.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        jpanel.add(jtable, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(jpanel);
        this.setTitle("Wydatki");
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private Object[][] findData(String nickName, String rok, String miesiac) throws SQLException {
        
        PreparedStatement prestmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        prestmt.setString(1, nickName);
        prestmt.setString(2, rok);
        prestmt.setString(3, miesiac);
        ResultSet resultSet = prestmt.executeQuery();

        final List<Object[]> tableContent = new ArrayList<>();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            final Object[] data = new Object[]{
                resultSet.getString("dzien"), resultSet.getString("Zywnosc"),
                resultSet.getString("Mieszkianie"), resultSet.getString("Media"),
                resultSet.getString("Transport"), resultSet.getString("Ubrania"),
                resultSet.getString("Rachunki"), resultSet.getString("Rozrywka"),
                resultSet.getString("Suma_wydatkow")
            };
            tableContent.add(data);
        }
        return tableContent.toArray(new Object[tableContent.size()][]);

    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы очень помогли!